# Make sequence record that is not in other table (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sequence

Hi can anyone here know how to create a table (mysql) that have a column, the record in the column is a sequence number that is not in particular table?

for example i have a column in table A with records: 1 3 5 6 and so on..

and i expect the record a column in table B will be like this: 2 4 7 and so on.

Comment: This is not a sequence record in term of mysql table. It can be done using custom or manual functions